# RequireJS Optimization Reference Error

Tags: javascript, command-line, requirejs

I am using RequireJS to organise my JS files. I am attempting optimize my files into one main JS file.

I am using the following command to do this:

```
/home/plugins/requireJS/build/build.sh name=main out=mesh-built.js baseUrl=/home/public_html/js/ includeRequire=true
```

The command produces the following error:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main

node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at eval at <anonymous> (/home/plugins/requireJS/bin/../build/jslib/requirePatch.js:147:21)
    at Function.<anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (/home/plugins/requireJS/bin/../build/jslib/requirePatch.js:147:21))
    at Function.load (/home/plugins/requireJS/bin/../build/jslib/requirePatch.js:147:21)
    at loadPaused (require.js:916:21)
    at require.js:958:21
    at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1207:17)
    at Function.load (/home/plugins/requireJS/bin/../build/jslib/requirePatch.js:150:29)
    at loadPaused (require.js:916:21)
    at require.js:958:21
    at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1207:17)
```

Does anyone know why it would be producing this error?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a problem with the order of the files to include. Make sure the JS file which defines the $() is included first.